# Empty and Zero Value

Tags: php

I need to check if an age is empty so I do:

```
empty($age);
```

But when the age is 0, it still thinks it is empty.

How can I check if the age is empty but allow a 0 to validate as not empty?

Comment: @CodeGodie `empty` uses `isset` along with a bunch of other tests (such as a test for the presence of `0`)

Comment: `if ($age == 0 || !empty($age))`

Comment: 5 answers to a topic with 500 duplicates. Please, search first....

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a hack, for example:

```
if($age != "" && $age == false){
 // Age = 0
}
```

You can use is_null() too.

Answer (score -1):

Why do not you define it all your own

```
function myempty($x)
{
  if(empty($x) || $x=0)
  retutn true;
  else
  return false;
}
```